# How to use annotations to control the size (number of entries) of a Java Map

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I need to be able to use annotations to control the size (number of entries) of a Java Map.

The following works for a Java List, but not for a Map:

```
    @XmlElement
    @Size(max = 2)
    public List<Mytype> getMytypes() { return mytypes; }

    @XmlElement
    @Size(max = 2)
    public Map<MyothertypeEnum, Myothertype> getMyothertypes() { return myothertypes; }
```

The generated schemas (using JAXB) for these look like:

For the List:

```
    <xsd:element name="mytypes" type="ns0:Mytype" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2"/>
```

For the Map:

```
    <xsd:element name="myothertypes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="key" type="ns0:MyothertypeEnum" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xsd:element name="value" type="ns0:Myothertype" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

How do I write the annotations such that the Map 'entry' element has a maximum size? I am trying to get the '@Size' annotation to apply to the 'entry' element.

I don't understand what the macOccurs means on the 'myothertypes' element. There should only be one map allowed, not 2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems that the schema generator is overwhelmed by this. With the generated schema you are allowed to have 0..2 maps with unlimited entries each. I don't know which mechanism says schemagen to respect Bean Validation annotations, but this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

@Size controls the size constraints on the collection, so it’s affecting the entire myothertypes map.

maxOccurs relates to the number of occurrences of the element.
To control number of entries, create a custom validation mechanism with a custom getter method, then apply size constraint logic.

java
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Map;

public class YourClass {
private Map<MyothertypeEnum, Myothertype> myothertypes;

```
// Getter method with custom size validation logic
@XmlElement
public Map<MyothertypeEnum, Myothertype> getMyothertypes() {
    if (myothertypes.size() > 2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("myothertypes map size exceeds maximum allowed size of 2");
    }
    return myothertypes;
}

// Other methods and annotations for Myothertypes
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my main goal is using the annotations to control the schema generation. Nothing I have found in my searches has shown how to annotate the Map to control the number of map entries.